# How to deploy contract with vanity address using truffle?

Tags: truffle

I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction at all, so maybe you know totally different solution for deploying contract with vanity addresses?

My current approach is this:

1. generate private key such that create contract with nonce = 0 will have vanity address
2. fund this account with ETH
3. deploy the contract

But I have a problem, my truffle migrations have 12 different contracts so I want to deploy only one of them using specific private key.

I managed to generate an ethereum private key which will create contract with desirable, let say 0x**33333**... address when CRATE with nonce 0:

```
"address":"0xad571ff7001055b9737826215548b3043a365e27",
"privKey":"b0c40801e0ef4e440541c2fa9e38f2e80297e8b73772d4fb8f7e361b3ee395f7",
"contract":"0x33333cea349b04af9cfe399a053203e3d70c2bba"
```

but if I do

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    deployer.then(async () => {
        await deployer.deploy(ContractA);
        // deploy many other contracts
        const privateKey = "b0c40801e0ef4e440541c2fa9e38f2e80297e8b73772d4fb8f7e361b3ee395f7";
        const accountCreate33333 = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
        await deployer.deploy(ContractB, {from: accountCreate33333});
    });
}
```

returns the error: "ContractB" -- Returned error: sender account not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HDWallet provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider). It accepts an arrays with private keys as argument.

Then calling the deployer with `{ from: account }` should just work (tm).